# iOS to web server via POST - string gets cut off?

Tags: ios, json, post

I'm trying to send a serialized object to a web server from my iOS app and generally it all works. I have tried sending a huge string and it comes out on the server just fine. But when I send a serialized object to the server, the string gets cut off. I have logged the string from my app - it's all there. I tried writing the same string to a file on my web server and it's cut off in the most weird way.

What could be the reason? I suspect this has something to do with the encoding. Here is how I send the data to the server:

```
+ (void)postRequestWithData:(id)data toURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // Prepare data
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *postDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sales=%@", postDataString];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestString length]];

    // Make the request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    // Error reporting
    if (!connection) {
        NSLog(@"Could not make a connection!");
    }
}
```

Where (id)data is an array of dictionaries.

Here is how I handle it in the server:

```
<?php
    $sales = $_POST['sales'];
    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $sales);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: `@"Current-Type"` should be `@"Content-Type"`...

Comment: Ah, thanks. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: Also, `[requestString length]` should be `strlen([requestString UTF8String]`.

Comment: Try using a different serialization method than pretty printing. I imagine pretty printing will include newline characters and such that might cause the PHP code to terminate the string prematurely.

Comment: @Jasarien Agreed, which one should I use? There are hundreds of methods and I'm not familiar with any of them.

Comment: With with 0 or NULL as an option instead of pretty printing.

Comment: Ok, no white spaces anymore, but still cut off at the same location.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your URL (query) string according to [application/x-www-form-urlencode](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1). There is an NSString function for this:

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

According to this, your code should look like:

```
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *postDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSSztring *escapedDataString = [postDataString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding]
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sales=%@", escapedDataString];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestString length]];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to URL encode your postDataString first. To do this you can use the Core Foundation function [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes).

```
NSString *encoded = CFBridgingRelease( CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes( kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)originalString, NULL, NULL, kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ) );
```

Both `NULL` parameters control which characters should be encoded and which should be left alone. Passing `NULL` for both escapes all characters that are invalid in URLs. Note that I am assuming ARC here.

Also your Content-Length calculation is wrong. You need to get the length from your `NSData` object, not the string.

Comment: I just solved it by manually replacing the & symbols in the string. Could this function CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes do that? I'm asking because I still don't know how to implement it :) If you can tell me that I can check your answer.